# wallpaper problem with kivymd screen manager

Tags: python, background, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I wanted to try to insert multiple screens into my application with screenmanager but when I started it the background from a dark color "md_bg_color: [22/255, 24/255, 28/255, 1]" became totally white and I can' don't change it

this is my
pyhton code:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel, MDIcon
from kivymd.uix.button import MDFlatButton, MDRectangleFlatButton
from kivymd.uix.textfield import MDTextField
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager


class FirstWindow(Screen):
    pass

class SecondiWindow(Screen):
    pass

class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MyApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Orange"
        self.theme_cls.primary_hue = 'A700'
        return
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

kivy code:

```
WindowManager:
    FirstWindow:
    SecondiWindow:

<SecondiWindow>:
    name: 'second'  
    md_bg_color: [22/255, 24/255, 28/255, 1]           
    MDBottomNavigation:
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen-1"
            text: 'chat'
            icon: 'chat'
            MDLabel: 
                text:"JAHF"
                halign: 'center'
        MDBottomNavigationItem:
            name: "screen-2"
            text: 'chadsdsadt'
            icon: "coffee"
            MDLabel: 
                text:"JAHFdsdsdds"
                halign: 'center'
 
<FirstWindow>:  
    name: "first"
    md_bg_color: [24/255, 24/255, 28/255, 1]
    MDCard:    
        size_hint: None,None
        size: 400,500
        pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5,'center_y': 0.5}
        elevation: 3
        md_bg_color: [30/255, 30/255, 32/255, 1]
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: (0,0,0,20)

        RelativeLayout:

            MDLabel:
                id: logo
                text: "TIKTOK+"
                text_size: self.size
                color: [205/255, 75/255, 8/255, 1]
                font_size: 30
                family_name: 'Helvetica'
                bold: True
                markup: True
                valign: 'top'
                halign: 'center'
                padding: (0,20,0,0)
                        
            MDTextField:
                id: user
                hint_text: 'Enter Username'
                helper_text: "or click on forgotten username or password"
                helper_text_mode: "on_focus"
                helper_text_color: 1,1,1,1
                hint_text_color_normal: 1,1,1,1
                line_color_normal: 1,1,1,1
                icon_right_color_normal: 1,1,1,1
                icon_right: "account"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 300
                font_size: 18
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.7}#, 'center_y': 0.5}
                        
                        
            MDTextField:
                id: password
                hint_text_color_normal: 1,1,1,1
                line_color_normal: 1,1,1,1
                icon_right_color_normal: 1,1,1,1
                hint_text: 'Enter Username'
                icon_right: "eye-off"
                size_hint_x: None
                width: 300
                font_size: 18
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.55}
                password: True

            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                id: login
                text: 'Login'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.7, 'center_y': 0.4}
                size_hint: 0.3, None

            MDRectangleFlatButton:
                id: register
                text: 'Registrati'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.3, 'center_y': 0.4}
                on_release: app.root.current = "second"
                
            MDLabel:
                text: "------------------   or   ------------------"
                text_size: self.size
                color: [1,1,1,1]
                font_size: 15
                family_name: 'Helvetica'
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.78}
                    
                halign: 'center'

            MDRoundFlatIconButton:
                id: google
                icon: "google"
                text: 'Continua con Google'
                icon_color: "white"
                text_color: "white"
                icon_right: "eye-off"
                pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}
                size_hint: 0.7, None
```

I thought the background color didn't change

Answer (score 0):

You are using a property of `MSCreen`, but your screens are not `MDScreens`. Try changing them in your code to:

```
class FirstWindow(MDScreen):
    pass


class SecondiWindow(MDScreen):
    pass


class WindowManager(MDScreenManager):
    pass
```